# FsrmQuotaManager set Quota in MegaBytes

Tags: c#, .net

i have a little Problem with some Quota on a Windows Server.

I try to set a quota for a directory.

My Code:

```
public void SetDirectoryQuota(string directory, int size, int threshold)
{
    Int64 quotaSize = (size * 1024 * 1024);
    IFsrmQuotaManager FSRMQuotaManager = new FsrmQuotaManager();
    IFsrmQuota Quota = null;
    try
    {
        Quota = FSRMQuotaManager.GetQuota(directory);
        Quota.QuotaLimit = quotaSize;
        Quota.AddThreshold(threshold);
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

The size is in Megabytes.

So when i try: size = 2000 the quota is correct (~1,95GB).
But when i try: size = 30000 the quota is also set to (~1,30GB) instead of 30GB.

Somebody can see my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change "size" from `int` to `Int64`.